# Loop through child elements of $element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to loop thorough all child element of an $element while creating a custom directive. Here is the code for controller of the directive.

```
        controller: function ($element, $scope) {
        $scope.showChildElementData = function () {
            var sameLevelElems = $element.children());

            for (var i = 0; i < sameLevelElems.length; i++) {
                console.log(sameLevelElems[i].data());
            }
        };
    }
```

Function call to data returns error

```
TypeError: Object #<HTMLLIElement> has no method 'data'
```

But I can do

```
sameLevelElems.data()
```

Which always returns the first elements data. How can I loop through all children?

Comment: Try `angular.element( sameLevelElems[i] ).data()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular's [`element`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element) has `data` method. So wrap your `sameLevelElems[i]` first , like this:

```
angular.element( sameLevelElems[i] ).data()
```